# Did the movie "Small Soldiers" produce any spin off toys?

Tags: marketing, small-soldiers

I loved the movie *Small Soldiers* (1998) for many reasons. Were there any toys made from the movie, especially the soldiers?

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4506/49).

Comment: Thank you! This was my first challenge! Archer tells me to seek out new challenges!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, [Hasbro made a line of Small Soldiers](https://www.figurerealm.com/actionfigure?action=seriesitemlist&id=208)

There's:

**Archer**

[image]

**Brick Bazooka**

[image]

**Chip Hazard**

[image]

**Flatchoo (with Nibble)**

[image]

**Freakenstein**

[image]

**Insaniac**

[image]

**Kip**

[image]

**Nick Nitro**

[image]

**Punch-It**

[image]

**Slamfist**

[image]

Witchdoctor Insaniac

[image]

There were also (ironically) larger 12" versions of Archer and Chip Hazard and a couple of vehicles. See link above for more information.

Comment: You are awesome! I assume that they were for the American market? I never saw them here in Australia.

Comment: There's more than a few for sale on eBay.

Comment: @arthornton I live in Australia, and a kid at school had a few of the figures.